# Should I use custom taxonomy or custom post type?

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, categories, custom-post-type

I've recently taken on a project from a client of mine, after a lot of persuasion I've managed to finally get the website under some kind of CMS. I'm pretty new to Wordpress I've come from an ExpressionEngine background and fancied trying something new for a change, so excuse the lack of knowledge (I'm trying my best! :D).

Now The issue I'm currently facing is that they have very specific directions regarding how they want their content displayed on their website and more importantly how they would like to manage it. They are a travel agent I'm currently putting together the resort directory that will display all of the resorts they offer.

In regards to the current structure of the directory it will be made up of 4 different sections. To give you a better understanding of how I want things to work take a look at this hierarchy below, (I've used turkey as an example, these would need to be dynamic):

- **/destinations/** 
   This will be our destinations page that will list
  all of the countries they currently
  offer. I imagine this to be a static
  page with some content about the
  countries on offer with a list of the
  countries below (These will be our
  parent taxonomies).
- **/destinations/turkey/**
   This will be our parent taxonomy. This
  page will also have to have the
  ability to add some static content to
  insert information about the country
  and its locations. Below this will be
  a second list, these will be the
  different areas of turkey (These will
  be children of the parent
  taxonomies).
- **/destinations/turkey/belek/**
   This will be our child taxonomy, This
  page will again need to have the
  ability to add some static content.
  It will also include our list of
  resorts that my client offers within
  this location (These will be our
  entries/posts).
- **/destinations/turkey/belek/resort-name**
  This will be our post/entry page,
  here we will have all of the
  information on the select resort, the
  specifics of this aren't an issue and
  I've already got this sorted.

Now, I've done a lot of reading up on custom post types, custom taxonomies and their abilities and uses but I'm hit with a situation at the moment where I can't decide on which route I should take. I've been experimenting over the last few hours with the setup of one custom post type (for resorts) and one hierarchical taxonomy (for locations). Which works some what ok BUT due to the limitations of the taxonomy UI within the admin panel it doesn't allow me to add my static content/images etc. (I'd much prefer to use a WYSIWYG especially from a clients point of view).

So this makes me wonder if it would be worth making two custom post types and scrapping taxonomies all together, making one of the post types resorts and the other locations. With the locations post type I could set it up like the pages module (which would give me hierarchical controls to allow me to organise my locations how I had originally planned) but is this a wise move? I mean from what I've read you shouldn't really organise content this way but I've got a feeling that maybe just a clash of contextual semantics (I could be wrong!). Would there be any limitations for me setting things up this way should I wish to add search functionality in the future? Or anything else for that matter?

I thought I'd mention this before I FINALLY click the submit button (apologies for the great wall of text) but pages... I've [read here](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/03/13/page-templates-the-untapped-potential-of-wordpress) that they are powerful little gems within Wordpress, how should I be taking advantage of these if I'm using custom taxonomies? How well do they work with listing categories are they what I need?

Right, that about wraps up everything I've got to ask for now - maybe I should have split this into a few posts but hey! I hope this gives you guys enough information about what I'm trying to achieve and please if I am going wrong feel free to point me in the right direction I'm really eager to learn more about Wordpress and it's capabilities.

Regards
Danny

Answer (score 1):

While this is one approach, it sounds like what you really want to be using (rather than custom post-taxonomies) is simply the Page functionality of WP. Everything you're describing is simply the hierarchical structure of the navigation of your pages. Yes, you can use the custom taxonomies to accomplish this same thing, but since you're describing things that tend to be "one" thing (ie: a single resort) you probably don't need the taxonomies.

You *might* want to look at another option: PODS CMS http://podscms.com

This will give you a simple structure to add custom features to your posts relatively easily... Things like pricing, amenities, and other "organizable" details can be stored using PODS and then referenced across your site for better usability. It might be worth a look!

Comment: +1 for evangelizing Pods.  A super-awesome wordpress plugin. And it would give him the URL structure and also a data-driven architecture. It would be **far** better than just using wordpress pages.